# No hyperlinks in resultset classic console or snowsight

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have seen many examples of having active hyperlinks in the resultset in either the classic console or snowsight in Snowflake. However, all i get is the text of the address and i cannot click on it. I did come across an article explaining it depends on the application. It also says that Chrome will make a hyperlink of the text. But that is not the case with me. Neither Edge or Chrome makes active hyperlinks of the addresses. Things i tried. Querying a directory table and see the result of the file_url field. The address is there, but no hyperlink. I also tried to create a custom table that holds a address, but also no hyperlink on the result. Is there a certain setting that i am missing in either classic console/Snowsigth or webbrowser?

Kick

Comment: [Downloading Staged Files in Snowsight](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/unstructured-intro.html#downloading-staged-files-in-snowsight) - "Users can click on a generated scoped, pre-signed, or file URL in the results table of a Snowsight worksheet and download the referenced file."

Answer (score 0):

I'm on MacOS, using Chrome.  The following query on Snowsight generates a result set that contains a url and is clickable:

```
select 'http://www.apnews.com' from dual;
```

Screenshot of result showing active URL:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jim and Lukasz, so if i understand it correctly. One needs to convert it to on of the three option. By itself the directory table does not genereate a clickable url, only text?

Comment: Can you show the query you're using and the results you get and post in the original question?